# wso2 custom synapse file is not copied over to newly created tenant

Tags: wso2

I have a multi-tenant wso2 API manager 1.10.0. I am developing a class mediator with business logic, which will be part of out sequence. I have put this new sequence file (xxx.xml) into (carbon-home)/repository/deployment/server/synapse-config/default/sequences directory, and restart the wso2 server. But when I create a new tenant, all other xml files in that directory get copied into the newly created tenant directory and SVN repository, but not my file.

Is there anything I need to do to tell wso2 server about my new sequence file so that it can pick it up?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new tenant, it will not create any custom files from super tenant. It will only create the default files that available on repository/deployment/server of a fresh pack.
Therefore you have to manually copy your custom file or create that artifact again using the management console (in tenant)